# How to solve PW Generator can´t handle specific Chars?

Tags: kotlin

I´m new to Kotlin so first I start with a Password Generator. I do use IntelliJIDea

```
fun main() {

var helper = Int
var counter = 0
val counterOfPwCha  = 10
var pwString = ""

val opportunityArray = arrayOf('A','C','a','c','B','b','D','d','E','e','F','f','#','+','*','$','%','&','§','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','k','K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    'l','L','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','Y','y','X','x','Z','z','<','>','|','?','!',)
while (counter <= counterOfPwCha)
{
    helper = (0..73).random()
    pwString += opportunityArray[helper]
    counter++
}
println(pwString)
}
```

it workes fine, but the output isn´t what I expected.
Example: +3�2L%II>J�
So it cant handle some of my Chars, I can debug it until I know what kind of Char he can´t handle with and delete them from the Array, but they are all some typical PW Chars, so my question is:
How can I let Kotlin know, how to Handle these ASCI2 chars?
Or is it because of the $?

Comment: I suspect it may be that the password generator is generating what the terminal would consider a special character code, though I may be entirely wrong. I can't think of any particular examples, except for the codes that you would use to print colour text in Linux; for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-output-colored-text-to-a-linux-terminal

Comment: Also, this isn't strictly answering your question, but take a look at the code for the password generator I wrote here: https://pl.kotl.in/bMCGiEdsv

Comment: Yeah for what it's worth the output seems fine to me - I'm running it here and not seeing any problems: https://pl.kotl.in/JSmZauMXr (had to fix ``helper = Int`` and the index count) so I think @MatthewLayton is right, and it's just that the terminal displaying the output that's interpreting them differently. For what it's worth, what you typed after **Example:** in the question is showing up with error symbols for me, like it's trying and failing to interpret stuff as UTF-8 or something. I know this isn't helpful by maybe it's a clue!

Comment: Guys your explanation helps me. I though i did something wrong, but your explanation makes sense to me. So thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid hardcoded numbers like the "73" in your range, it's way too error prone!

If you still get funny characters, put in some println that shows each character's numeric value so that you can lookup it using "man ascii".

A more Kotlin-like code would be:

```
fun pwgen() {
    val counterOfPwCha = 10

    val charset = ('A'..'Z') + ('a'..'z') + ('0'..'9') + listOf('#', '+', '*', '$', '%', '&', '§', '<', '>', '|', '?', '!')
    val pwString = (1..counterOfPwCha)
        .map {
            val randomArrayIndex = charset.indices.random()
            charset[randomArrayIndex]
        }
        .onEach { c -> println("Character $c = " + c.toInt()) }
        .joinToString("")

    println(pwString)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main() {

var helper = Int
var counter = 0
val counterOfPwCha  = 10
var pwString = ""

val opportunityArray = arrayOf('A','C','a','c','B','b','D','d','E','e','F','f','#','+','*','$','%','&','§','G','g','H','h','I','i','J','j','k','K','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
    'l','L','M','m','N','n','O','o','P','p','Q','q','R','r','S','s','T','t','U','u','V','v','W','w','Y','y','X','x','Z','z','<','>','|','?','!',)
while (counter <= counterOfPwCha)
{
    helper = (0..73).random()
    pwString += opportunityArray[helper]
    counter++
}
println(pwString)
}
```

Comment: i keep my code and vote them as Answer.
Maybe someone finds it usefull.
Comment of Matthew Layton can help someone too.